# try catch non working if I not provide the alias in a join (Ambiguous column name 'name')

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would need to help to understand why the CATCH is not catching the error.
SCENARIO 1 - working OK.

```
BEGIN TRY

if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not NULL drop table #temp
create table #temp (name varchar(1))

insert into #temp
values
('AA')

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;

END CATCH
```

> ERROR_MESSAGE: String or binary data would be truncated.

SCENARIO 2
(where I forget to put the alias for the column)

```
BEGIN TRY

if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not NULL drop table #temp
create table #temp (name varchar(1))

if object_id('tempdb..#temp01') is not NULL drop table #temp01
create table #temp01 (name varchar(1))


insert into #temp
values ('A')

insert into #temp01
values ('A')

select name
from #temp a
join #temp01 b on a.name = b.name

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;

END CATCH
```

In this case the error is not caught.
Can someone please explain why?

Thanks

Comment: TRY/CATCH does not catch compilation errors.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, would do you mean? I don't get it ^^

Answer (score 0):

TRY/CATCH is a runtime construct. In order to get to CATCH, your code has to *run*. Your code can’t run if it has a parse or compilation error. An even simpler example is the following:

```
BEGIN TRY;
  SELECT; -- or SELECT foo; or any invalid syntax
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH;
  PRINT 1;
END CATCH;
```

CATCH never happens here because `SELECT;` is invalid T-SQL and fails parsing, very much like your ambiguous column fails parsing, preventing CATCH from happening because the code *never runs*:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

We can look at it the other way around too, so we don't get too hung up on CATCH "failing" to capture compilation errors. What if the

```
BEGIN TRY;
  SELECT 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH;
  PRINT; -- invalid syntax!
END CATCH;
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>
> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Note the line number: the syntax error here is inside CATCH, which *shouldn't* be reached, given that everything in TRY should work just fine. However, as with the previous example, the code inside both TRY and CATCH has to *compile* before it can *run*. If it can't compile, it's going to fail before TRY or CATCH ever become a thing.